# How to connect multiple tables with different relations and use attach() in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relation, multiple-tables

I'm trying to manage the roles of the (initial) user upon sign up in my project using Laravel 5.3. I have already got it working the first time but I had to add another table and now I'm lost.

I have 4 tables, **Company**, **User**, **Role** and a **pivot table** for the User and Role named **Role_Users**

**Company Table** has **comp_id**

**User Table** has **comp_id**, **user_id**

**Role Table** has **role_id**, **role_desc**

**Role_Users Table** has **comp_id**, **user_id**, **role_id**

---

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable{
    public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'comp_id');
     }

    public function roles(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
}
```

---

**Role Model**

```
class Role extends Model{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_users')->withTimeStamps();
    }

    public function comp(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'role_users')->withTimeStamps();
    }

}
```

---

**Company Model**

```
class Company extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'comp_id';  

    public function members(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'comp_id');
    }

    public function roles(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Role', 'role_users')->withTimeStamps();
    }
}
```

---

The system goes like this:

```
each **User** belongs to many **Role**
each **Role** belongs to many **User**
```

The relation between the User, Role and Role_Users part has already been working fine. But I had to change and add a **Company** field to each table because it will be used by many company who'd like to try the program.

```
each **Company** has many **User**
each **User** belongs to **Company**
```

I'm trying to use **attach()** like this:

**Account Controller**

```
 public function setupaccountcomplete($comp, $user){
    $comp_id = $comp;
    $user_id = $user;

    $updateData = [];
    $updateData['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $updateData['user_sex'] = Input::get('user_sex');
    $updateData['user_civilstatus'] = Input::get('user_civilstatus');
    $updateData['user_birthday'] = Input::get('user_bday');
    $updateData['user_birthplace'] = Input::get('user_bplace');
    $updateData['user_address'] = Input::get('user_address');
    $updateData['user_mobile'] = Input::get('user_mobile');
    $updateData['user_landline'] = Input::get('user_landline');
    $updateData['user_email'] = Input::get('user_email');
    $updateData['user_zip'] = Input::get('user_zip');
    $updateData['user_nationality'] = Input::get('user_nationality');
    $updateData['user_religion'] = Input::get('user_religion');
    $updateData['user_educAttain'] = Input::get('user_educAttain');
    $updateData['user_school'] = Input::get('user_school');
    $updateData['user_schooladdress'] = Input::get('user_schooladdress');
    $updateData['user_addedby'] = $user_id;

    $updatesql = DB::table('users')
        ->where('user_id', '=', $updateData['user_id'])
        ->update(['user_sex' => $updateData['user_sex'],
            'user_civilstatus' => $updateData['user_civilstatus'],
            'user_bday' => $updateData['user_birthday'],
            'user_bplace' => $updateData['user_birthplace'],
            'user_address' => $updateData['user_address'],
            'user_mobile' => $updateData['user_mobile'],
            'user_landline' => $updateData['user_landline'],
            'user_landline' => $updateData['user_landline'],
            'user_zip'=> $updateData['user_zip'],
            'user_religion'=> $updateData['user_religion'],
            'user_nationality' => $updateData['user_nationality'],
            'user_educAttain' => $updateData['user_educAttain'],
            'user_school' => $updateData['user_school'],
            'user_schooladdress' => $updateData['user_schooladdress'],
            'user_addedby' => $updateData['user_addedby']
            ]);

    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('role_desc', 'Superadmin')->first());

    return Redirect::route('setupcooperative', array('comp' => $comp_id, 'user' => $user_id));

}
```

With my **AccountController** the user has a role_id of "1" but the comp_id is empty.

Can someone help me? I think my relations in the model is wrong. Also, I am getting a *Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::roles()* when I try to do this line:

```
 $user->company()->roles()->attach(Role::where('role_desc', 'Superadmin')->first());
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Laravel docs, `attach()` takes in the ID of the role you are attaching, not the Role itself:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

`$user->roles()->attach(Role::where('role_desc', 'Superadmin')->first());`

should be:

`$user->roles()->attach(Role::where('role_desc', 'Superadmin')->get('id')->first());`

Comment: I'm getting a BadMethodCallException: Method roles does not exist.

Comment: Also, you don't really describe the relationship between Role and Company.  I think the roles() method on the Company class needs to return a belongsToMany.  As stated on the Laravel docs, Many-To-Many relationships are defined on both ends by returning a belongsToMany().

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

If the relation between Company and Roles is not Many-Many, and is instead One-Many, then you will use the hasOne and hasMany to define the relations.

Comment: Sorry, to define the One side of One-Many, use belongsTo(), not hasOne.